# How do I hide a div when the channel entries tag it contains has no results?

Tags: ee2, tags

In the margin of my blog, I list featured articles. This is the code.
My problem: I don´t always have stuff to feature. When the channel entries tag is empty a grey box with the title Featured is left over. I dont want to use a conditional, that says 
"if no entry, then print "Nothing to feature yet"."
I want to get rid of the entire box. How can i do this?

```
<div class="panel">
  <h5>Featured</h5>
  {exp:channel:entries channel="blog" limit="2" status="featured"}
    <p><a href="{url_title_path='eintrag/index'}">{title}</a></p>
  {/exp:channel:entries}
</div>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Bring the `<div>` inside your channel entries tag and do something like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog" limit="2" status="featured"}
  {if count == 1}
  <div class="panel">
    <h5>Featured</h5>
  {/if}
      <p><a href="{url_title_path='eintrag/index'}">{title}</a></p>
  {if count == total_results}
  </div>
  {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

ie, output the opening `<div>` and `<h5>` only on the first item in the loop, and only output the closing `<div>` on the last item in the loop. This way no content is output if there are no results.

You can also optionally handle the `no_results` condition specially using the [`{if no_results}` conditional](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#if-no-results).

Comment: Np. If you're sure that answers your question it would be great if to click the arrow underneath the vote controls to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: I'm curious: why limit="2" and not limit="1"? I've been having a problem with a similar situation where I have limit="1" not working.

Comment: @edward I purely used `limit="2"` as that was what the questioner used in their code example - `limit="1"` should work too, though if you only want one entry you shouldn't need any `count` based conditionals inside the loop anyway, as the loop will only run through once